# When using Proguard, the size of the lib file in the apk increases significantly. How do I prevent this?

Tags: java, android, proguard

When using Proguard, the size of the **lib** file in the apk increases significantly.

[apk folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri8dg.png)

Proguard worked correctly in the **classes.dex** file, but the entire lib folder size is increasing.

I tried adding some rules to the **proguard-rules.pro** file but it didn't work.

Comment: Proguard does not add something to the lib folder. Most you have disabled the abi filter so more libraries are in the lib folder. Simply check the lib folder content.

Comment: "android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
}" I used this code in the document and my problem was solved, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
}
```

I used this code in the document and my problem was solved.